# Django migrations on celery not stoping after .save()

Tags: django, celery, django-migrations, celery-task, django-tenants

I have a django application and celery, and one of the tasks is to create a tenant in '/admin'

```
@app.task
def create_tenant_account(form_data):
   ...
   tenant = Company(...)
   tenant.save()
   ...
```

After tenant.save() all of the migrations start applying, but suddenly the celery crashes because the code dont stoped after tenant.save() (after the save, I have some tenants setup that needs to run after)

This only happens on celery, locally it stops and runs normally.

Is there a way to prevent the code from runing?

My solution was to create another function to run after the tenant.save(), but for now, I need the setup to run in the same function.